# How to put image and itemname in NSToolbar?

Tags: cocoa

I have created desktop application for mac.I want to put some image and item name on the customize toolbar.I dont know how to implement that things.can you give me some advice for that.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In interface builder, double-click on an empty space on the toolbar and it will open up. You can drag an NSToolbarItem to the open area. You can then add a name, an image, and hook up an action to the toolbar item in the inspector.